# pedir que escriba el mismo mensaje que le aparece en C

Tags: c, caracteres, imprimir

si imprimo una cadena de caracteres, me gustaría saber la forma en la cual pedirle al usuario que escriba la misma frase que le aparece en pantalla.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

 char cadena[] = "Hola mundo";
 int indice;
 for (indice = 0; indice < strlen(cadena); indice++){
 char actual = cadena[indice];
 printf("%c", actual);

 }

}
```

Comment: Creo que ni tú mismo entiendes lo que quieres obtener, porque he leído tu pregunta 7 veces y sigo sin ser capaz de entender lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Vas por buen camino. Solo te falta pedir la cadena, que puedes hacerlo con [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) o [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets). [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) te será útil.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está faltando sería colocar un

```
printf("mensaje");
```

En el que le dirías al usario qe ecriba la misma cadena que acaba de ver,  definir un array char (así como el que tenías) definiendo el tamaño, de esta manera

```
char array [longitud maxima];
```

Y luego para que el  usuario introduzca la cadena un

```
scanf(" %s",&array);
```